# Convert razor syntax to plain html using razorEngine

Tags: c#, razorengine

I am trying to convert razor view syntax to plain HTML using a library called [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine) But when I run the below code, it gives me `localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500` during the line of `var result`.

What am I doing wrong?

Controller code:

```
string template = @"Hi @Model.Name";

            var model = new UserModel() { Name = "Sarah" };

            var result = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, "templateKey", null, model);
```

Model:

```
public class UserModel
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: You mean *render* the Razor template into HTML

Comment: Yes. I want to render Razor template into html

Comment: Something must be wrong with `Engine.Razor.RunCompile()` but what i am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [quickstart](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine#quickstart), passing `null` into:

```
var result = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, "templateKey", null, model);
```

means you are using a dynamic model.

Since you are not using a dynamic model, you need to specify the model type:

```
var result = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, "templateKey", typeof(UserModel), model);
```